# CSS selector not found error.? warning in VScode

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[image]

A sudden warning message came in while I was working on my project, It is showing that CSS class is not found but in my code every class is linked in CSS. Can anyone help me out with this? Why is this sudden warning.

[image]

Comment: It means those classes do not appear in your HTML file.

Comment: It is there in my html file, that is the reason i posted in stack overflow, i am not getting  why it is showing.

Comment: If you can't demonstrate the problem we can't help. Images of code are not acceptable.

Comment: Check your extensions in VS Code related html css may be they are updated automatically and required reloading.

Comment: @AliMirza All the extensions are updated.

Comment: @AravindaKS Can you list extensions you used for HTML CSS ?

Comment: @AliMirza Yeah sure!, 1.HTML CSS Support  2.IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML
3.CSS Peek

Comment: @AravindaKS I think 1.HTML CSS Support is making problem here remove it and reload the VScode

Comment: @AliMirza Yeah, thank you so much. But can I know the reason? Till this date it was not making any problem but today it showed like this. Does the extensions also make problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226613/discussion-between-aravinda-ks-and-ali-mirza).

Answer (score 2):

Remove HTML CSS Support extension from VS code because it causes this issue in latest update or you can downgrade the extension version.

Comment: After removing the extension, i am not able to add external link, html is not supporting only. any changes made in html and css is not affecting.

Comment: @AravindaKS if you want to use this extension you can downgrade it until the problem is solved from extension developers end.